# How to deal with two submit buttons in a form?

Tags: php, html, php-5.3, shopping-cart

I don't understand this,

if I do this and I click the **check out button**, the page won't go to the **check out page**,

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" id="form-cart">
<button name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="Update cart">Update cart</button>
<button name="checkout" id="checkout" type="submit" value="Check out">Check out</button>
</form>
```

It only does if I change the `name="checkout"` to `name="cart-checkout"`,

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" id="form-cart">
<button name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="Update cart">Update cart</button>
<button name="cart-checkout" id="checkout" type="submit" value="Check out">Check out</button>
</form>
```

It works that way but does not make any sense to me, do you know why it does it that way?

So I tried to use `<a>` tag inside the `<button>` tag and it goes to the check out page,

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" id="form-cart">
<button name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="Update cart">Update cart</button>
<button name="checkout" id="checkout" type="submit" value="Check out"><a href="checkout.php">Check out</a></button>
</form>
```

But does it a **valid html** to put `<a>` tag inside the `<button>` tag?

Comment: HTML doesn't handle form interactions, PHP (or other server side scripts) handles the input. You'd have to post the PHP code, but I'm going to assume you're using code that someone else has written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change the buttons to:

```
<input name="update" id="update" type="submit" value="Update cart">
<input name="cart-checkout" id="checkout" type="submit" value="Check out">
```

Then in PHP (on cart.php) you can do:

```
<?php
  if($_POST){
     if(isset($_POST['update']){
       // process update
     } else if(isset($_POST['cart-checkout']){
       // process cart checkout
       // or uncomment the below line to forward to checkout.php
       // header("Location: checkout.php");
     }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about making one `<button>` that simply acts like a `<a href="">` ?

-edit-

Whoops, sorry, misread. `<button onclick="window.location='/nextpage';">` ?

Comment: thanks Tom! I thought of that but it does not look consistent with the other submit button but not going to use that... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use JavaScript here with an `onclick` event, which will take you to the checkout page.

Comment: thanks. I thought of that. but I would avoid js at this stage so that the page can fall back to html when js has been disable.